# storage/emulated/0/YourName.png: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to take an user Screenshot, I used this code. I was take 3 permission, READ_EXTERNAL_STORE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORE, and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Problem not fix. It show open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

```
public void tackeAndSaveScreenShot(Activity mActivity) {
        View MainView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        MainView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        MainView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap MainBitmap = MainView.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();

        mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        //to remove statusBar from the taken sc
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
        //using screen size to create bitmap
        int width = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        Bitmap OutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainBitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);
        MainView.destroyDrawingCache();
        try {

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            //you can also using current time to generate name
            String name="YourName";
            File file = new File(path, name + ".png");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            OutBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 1000, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            //this line will add the saved picture to gallery
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I check on my Logcat. they show the problem is in

```
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

I get permission properly.

```
private void userPermission2(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length > 0
        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userPermission2();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

I tried many why but don'work. Every time is the same problem.

The log is.

```
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10351; state: ENABLED
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/YourName.png: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.tackeAndSaveScreenShot(MainActivity.java:93)
W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7570)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7525)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3900(View.java:836)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28680)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8243)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8125)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
W/System.err:   ... 16 more
```

Comment: Since Android 11 (API 30) you no longer have full access to all storage with those permissions: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage. Either target Android 10 or read and understand that page. There's no trivial "replace that code and it will work" type fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ```
> >         String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
> > ```

Change to:

```
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
```

And for Android 10 devices add `android:legacyExternalStorage="true"` to application tag in manifest file.

For Android 13+ devices you do not need any permission.