# how to create dir and File in Android Studio api 30 or higher with java

Tags: java, android

I wrote an app for android 7 and it worked good.
But in android 12 my app is not working .Because in my app i create  directory pdf and write to pdf file with below code.
Why it's not working on android 12.
I add this code to manifests

```
`requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
File root = null;
root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/pdf");
if (!dir.exists()) {
dir.mkdir();
}
filename = CustomerName + ".pdf";
myFile = new File(dir, filename);
fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

`

Comment: If it is not working, do you at least get some kind of error message?! if yes then share it as well

Comment: `if (!dir.mkdir()) return;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370900/storage-emulated-0-yourname-png-open-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted/75372243#75372243

Comment: do you declare "android.manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in manifest and also granted in application?

Comment: I use this code   
root=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
but when i delete file from "pdf" folder  and  create file again i have this error message 
"open failed: EEXIST (File exists)"